# Is it possible to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext from connectionDidFinishLoading?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

I got these errors when the code below is executed:

```
[Switching to process 74682 thread 0x2003]
[Switching to process 74682 thread 0x207]
[Switching to process 74682 thread 0x720f]
```

--

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  UIImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.resp_data;
  CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(150);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
  CGRect image_rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,itemSize.width,itemSize.height);
  [image drawInRect:image_rect];
  self.image_view.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // image_view ivar is connected to a UIImageView in the View associated to this controller
  self.resp_data = nil;
  self.imageConnection = nil;
  [image release];

}
```

Any idea what could be the issue and how to solve it ? (and of course the expected image does not show up)

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TESTED CODE:100% WORKS**

```
 #define kAppIconHeight 48

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Set appIcon and clear temporary data/image
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.resp_data];

    if (image.size.width != kAppIconHeight && image.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
    {
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [image drawInRect:imageRect];
        self.image_view.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        self.image_view.image = image;
    }

    self.resp_data = nil;
    [image release];

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    //self.imageConnection = nil;

    // call our delegate and tell it that our icon is ready for display
    //      [delegate appImageDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView];
}
```

Comment: @Nag_iphone welcome buddy. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Comment: come to iphone / ipad chat room